# Java security error: validity check failed

Tags: java, gradle, certificate

Currently working on my Rasberry Pi Zero, and am getting this error when I try to build a gradle project. I can't seem to find anything online that talks about this. Can someone point me in the right direction? I run `./gradlew build`, which yields this:

```
Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.3-bin.zip

Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: validity check failed
        at sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131)
        at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:324)
        at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:267)
        at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:262)
        at sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:654)
        at sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.onCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:473)
        at sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.consume(CertificateMessage.java:369)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:377)
        at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:444)
        at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:422)
        at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:182)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:152)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1392)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1300)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:435)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:197)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1572)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1500)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:268)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.downloadInternal(Download.java:78)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.download(Download.java:63)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:68)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:48)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:69)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:107)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:63)
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: validity check failed
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doValidate(PKIXValidator.java:386)
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:291)
        at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:271)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:315)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:223)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:129)
        at sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:638)
        ... 23 more
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: validity check failed
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXMasterCertPathValidator.validate(PKIXMasterCertPathValidator.java:135)
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.validate(PKIXCertPathValidator.java:220)
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.validate(PKIXCertPathValidator.java:140)
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.engineValidate(PKIXCertPathValidator.java:79)
        at java.security.cert.CertPathValidator.validate(CertPathValidator.java:292)
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doValidate(PKIXValidator.java:381)
        ... 29 more
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateNotYetValidException: NotBefore: Mon Jan 27 12:48:08 GMT 2020
        at sun.security.x509.CertificateValidity.valid(CertificateValidity.java:273)
        at sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl.checkValidity(X509CertImpl.java:677)
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.BasicChecker.verifyValidity(BasicChecker.java:190)
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.BasicChecker.check(BasicChecker.java:144)
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXMasterCertPathValidator.validate(PKIXMasterCertPathValidator.java:125)
        ... 34 more
```

The closest thing I found dealt with the age of the JDK. I ran `sudo apt-install default-jdk`, which returned this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
default-jdk is already the newest version (2:1.8-58+deb9u1+b3).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 280 not upgraded.
```

Thanks!

Comment: **Check if your system clock is _way_ behind** with `date`

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem with the help of @dave_thompson_085. Unfortunately, my Raspberry Pi does not have an RTC, so it never remembered the date when I restarted it. I'm afraid there isn't a permanent solution to my scenario, but by running `timedatectl set-ntp 0` and `timedatectl set-time "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss"`, I was able to fix it to build the project.